# Outlook 2013 wont send email

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

We've been debugging an issue all day and simply can't find the answer.

One employee's computer cant send email. All others are fine.

So far we've

- Started Outlook in safe mode
- repair/reinstall Office 2013
- clean boot
- removed/readded the account
- repaired the pst file
- uninstalled the AV (Kaspersky)

It worked for a few min after the AV uninstall, but not for long.

We've wireshared the SMTP traffic and see that after the server replies

> 354 End data with .

The client doesn't send data. 3 seconds later the client sends a `RSET` (which is ACKd by the server). Then 60 seconds later it sends a `QUIT` and hangs up, then reconnects and tries again.

We don't know what else to try :(

Comment: Are you connecting to an exchange server?

Comment: Nope. Plesk server running Postfix and courier-imap.

Comment: Did you try creating a new mail profile and setting up your account in the new profile? https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Create-a-new-e-mail-profile-456cda43-b439-4dd8-b28f-01939538e3ba?ui=en-US&rs=en-ZA&ad=ZA

Comment: Did you check the user profile to see if it was set up correctly? Also the email server setup.

Comment: Does turning off the Windows Firewall make a difference?

Comment: Enable logging to see if it reveals anything which might help you figure this out - [Outlook 2013, 2010, & 2007: Enable/Disable Logging](http://www.technipages.com/outlook-enable-disable-logging). Also, check the Event Viewer for errors. Add what you find to your question.

Comment: New profile seems to have fixed the issue! Thanks @slayernoah

Comment: If it comes back, we'll try the logging thing and check the event viewer @CharlieRB

Comment: @Slashterix Glad to know it helped. I have added the same as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create a new Outlook profile and setup the account in the new profile.

A profile consists of accounts, data files, and settings that specify where your email messages are saved.

1. Exit Outlook.
2. In Control Panel, click or double-click Mail.

Mail appears in different Control Panel locations depending on the version of the Microsoft Windows operating system, Control Panel view selected, and whether a 32- or 64-bit operating system or version of Microsoft Outlook is installed.

3. Click Show Profiles.
4. Click Add.
5. Type a name for the profile, and then click OK.
6. Delete the old profile if needed.
7. Open Outlook using the new profile.

Reference: [Create an Outlook profile](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Create-an-Outlook-profile-f544c1ba-3352-4b3b-be0b-8d42a540459d)